# Sharing violation when writing to file

Tags: c#, file, serialization

I have a basic script that creates a directory/file if it does not exist but it gives me a sharing violation error. I am not sure why that is happening.

This is my current code:

```
    private static void SetDirectory(string folder, string filename, string extension)
    {
        _stringBuilder.Clear();

        string path = Application.persistentDataPath;

        _stringBuilder.Append(path);
        _stringBuilder.Append("/");
        _stringBuilder.Append(folder);
        _stringBuilder.Append("/");

        string directory = _stringBuilder.ToString();
        if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        }
        _stringBuilder.Append(filename);
        _stringBuilder.Append(".");
        _stringBuilder.Append(extension);

        string file = _stringBuilder.ToString();
        if (!File.Exists(file))
        {
            File.Create(file);
        }
    }

    public static void Save<T>(T data, string folder, string filename, string extension)
    {
        SetDirectory(folder, filename, extension);

        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtility.SerializeValue(data, DataFormat.JSON);
        File.WriteAllBytes(_stringBuilder.ToString(),bytes);
    }
```

I call the save method like so:

```
    public void Save()
    {
        SaveLoadManager.Save(_waypoints,"maps","waypoints","json");
        SaveLoadManager.Save(_edges,"maps","edges","json");
    }
```

It seems to work if i comment out the second save method call. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return a `FileStream`:

```
File.Create(file);
```

Because you aren't closing the file / disposing of this, your application is keeping the file open.

You then try to write to the same file here:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(_stringBuilder.ToString(),bytes);
```

Which sees that it's already opened (by `File.Create`) and then errors out.

You have two solutions:

1. Don't create the file at all. It's **completely unnecessary** as `File.WriteAllBytes(...)` will create the file if it doesn't exist.
2. Wrap the `File.Create(file);` in a `using` tag as below.
3. Return the created stream from `SetDirectory` and write to the stream.

If you have to create the file before writing to it, for whatever reason, you can simply wrap `File.Create(file)` in a `using` tag, which will dispose of the stream immediately after the file has been created, meaning that your program will no longer be locking the file.

```
using (File.Create(file));
```

Comment: Will it also create the directory as well making my directory creation code redundant too ?

Comment: No, it won't create a directory for you.